# How to get System date format in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date

I am developing MVC application.

I am using Date picker and I would like to set format used by the System.

Please let me know how can I get the date format used by system.

For example if system date is '01/25/2018',How can i get the format as 
'mm/dd/yyyy' which is used by system.

I have tried using `Date.toLocaleDateString()` which is returning the date value.

My requirement is only get the date format used by system.

Please let me know if there is anyway to know the format.

Comment: "*Please let me know how can I get the date format used by system*". You can't. There is no standard API to access host system settings for date formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Date simple throgh js like this:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
  dd='0'+dd;
 } 
 if(mm<10){
  mm='0'+mm;
 } 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
document.getElementById("systemdate").value = today;
```

```html
Date: <input id='systemdate'>
```

or something in short like

```js
var today = new Date() //gives date.
var formatted_date= today.toLocaleDateString(); //your required format
document.getElementById("systemdate").value = formatted_date;
```

```html
   Date: <input id=systemdate>
```

Comment: How does that format the date according to "*the date format used by system*"? The two examples above return differently formatted dates for me.

Comment: @RobG, as per my understanding,he wants something that runs in client system. not in server side.
  this runs in the browser console. as a pure `js` . so it will get you the system date only.

Comment: By "system" I assume the OP means "host system", so my comment is in regard to client side.